# How to save user information (userName) firebase new angular 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, firebase, angularfire

I need to save in my Firebase UserName and get it when he is LogIn, but I cant figure out it. What should I add in code?

```
  signUp(userEmail , userPassword){
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // ...
    });

 signIn(userEmail , userPassword){
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

Thank you for answers.

Comment: Doesn't that code create users already? What makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: I want to add UserName  but i can use only email and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem . You just chain function then it will look like

```
 firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword).then(function (result) {

  firebase.database().ref('/users/' + result.uid).set({
    username: 'someOne',
    email:userEmail,
  });

  console.log(result);
}).catch(function (error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```